# how to change relative layout shape similar to image in android

Tags: android

I have an cup shape image.
i want to change my relative layout exactly same as my imageview,
is it possible in android?

Any help?
Thanks

Change layout like this image

[image: Change layout like this image]

[Imageview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdScR.png)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For what purpose do you want your layout like to be so?

In one word, **it's impossible.**

Android View must be Rectangle shaped although they can store non-rectangle shape images inside.

Comment: i want to  roll out ball image into my cup shape image so i need a layout into cup shape

Comment: @aaa Then you can use wrap-contented RelativeLayout which contains ImageView which contains cup image and well-clipped to fit to the image. Anyway View Should be rectangular shaped.

Comment: Is it possible to change layout shape into cup shape by changing its vertices?

Comment: @aaa No you can't. View itself cannot escape the rectangular shape. Instead you can just add a cup image with transparent background.

Comment: Is it possible to change layout vertices?

Comment: @aaa Yes, if your Layout already have a parent you can do something like this : LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) yourRelativeLayout.getLayoutParam(); lp.width = yourWidth; lp.height = yourHeight; yourRelativeLayout.setLayoutParam(lp);

Comment: @aaa You can adjust the point by modifying margin. LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) yourRelativeLayout.getLayoutParam(); lp.topMargin = yourY; lp.leftMargin = yourX; yourRelativeLayout.setLayoutParam(lp);

Comment: Please see above image i have added now i want to change those vertices

Comment: I'm sorry, as I said, basic Android Views cannot take non-rectangular shape. If it is the critical point for you to make the exact View shape like the photo, I think you have to use OpenGL SurfaceView with camera working, and that is kinda tricky

Comment: Is it possible to draw that shape using openGL

Comment: Yes, but you can draw that shape with RelativeLayout too. Just add an Image you wanna show, with transparent background color. Shaping the View itself like parallelogram is not possible.

Comment: What i exactly need is i want to roll out balls inside of cup image is there any other library or idea you have,i done this inside relative layout but i want to do it inside of imageview

Comment: @aaa make 2 ImageViews, one contains semi-transparent cup image, and other contains ball image. place cup ImageView in front of ball ImageView. Make a tranlation Matrix for your ball Inageview and apply with animation. This is somewhat complex to explain...

Comment: Yes it's works but i want to add moreball  imageview dynamically

Comment: @aaa If you want to make balls move individually you have to make ImageViews Individually, along with same numbers of Matrice. Make sure Cup Image is always on top.

Comment: You know any library to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use ImageView in RelativeLayout set imageview to

```
imageView.bringToFront();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps :

```
    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/root"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/rel_actionbar"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:padding="4dp">
     <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel_screenshot"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_to_print"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
      </RelativeLayout>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_tshape"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/img_t"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Set `imgTShape.bringToFront();` In java file As Milan Suggested and use Transparent image for this. 
Use   `relScreenShot.addView(imgPrint, 0);` to add view dynamically inside the layout and set image in `imgprint` that will remain inside the root layout only.

Comment: I will add  more images into relative layout dynamically but it will roll out only inside of img_tshape image ,is it possible?